# Template Missing error on update only

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Still getting my sea legs with Ruby, Rails, and ActiveRecord...

Currently, I am integrating flash notices into my application (rails 4, ruby 2.1). I've started with my MetaCategory activerecord class. I'm using ajax to move data back and forth. So, to implement the flash messages, I've structured the create, update, and destroy action views like this:

Create.js.erb / Update.js.erb / Destroy.js.erb:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
    $('#flash_messages').html("<div class='alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(type) %> alert-dismissible' role='alert'><buttonclass='close' data-dismiss='alert'>×</button><%= message.html_safe%></div>")
<% end %>
```

My problem is this: On create and destroy, my flash messages are displayed as they should be. On update, they are not displayed.

Here's the code for the create, update, and destroy activities in the MetaCategories controller. I should point out that in the code for **update**, I have tried several different tactics, and they result in two different responses.

If I forgo the respond_to do.. render.. end, I receive a missing template error (trace below). If I put it in, I no longer receive the error. In both cases, I do NOT see the flash messages. What puzzles me further is that the update code is the only code that seems to require the respond_to do. Destroy and Create don't seem to care. (did I mention I'm new to the rails world?)

Anyhow, the code:

```
  def create
    # TODO: need uniqueness test for new Metas
    if params[:commit]=='Save'
      if current_user.try(:admin?)
            @meta_category = MetaCategory.create(meta_category_params)
        flash[:notice]='Meta category has been created.'
      else
        MetaCategoryProposedChange.create(new_meta_category: meta_category_params[:name],
                                          proposing_user_id: current_user.id)
        flash[:notice]='Your proposed new meta category has been recorded. You will be notified when it has been reviewed.'
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    # TODO: need uniqueness test for updated Metas
    if current_user.try(:admin?)
      @meta_category.update(meta_category_params)
      flash[:notice]='Meta category has been updated.'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render 'update.js.erb', json: @meta_category }
      end
    else
      MetaCategoryProposedChange.create(meta_category_id: @meta_category.id,
                                        new_meta_category: meta_category_params[:name],
                                        proposing_user_id: current_user.id)
      flash[:notice]='Your proposed change has been recorded. You will be notified when it has been reviewed.'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render 'update.js.erb', json: @meta_category, :status => 400 }
      end
    end

  end

  def destroy
    if current_user.try(:admin?)
      @meta_category.destroy
      flash[:notice]='Meta category has been deleted.'
    end
  end
```

The trace:

```
Started PUT "/meta_categories/95" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-25 11:10:56 -0500
Processing by MetaCategoriesController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"meta_category"=>{"name"=>"#BETABETA"}, "authenticity_token"=>"+Ui6n7tpUPRbGsmFW7RXGbH461Y0UueGSVmi8GlKjqY=", "id"=>"95"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
  MetaCategory Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `meta_categories`.* FROM `meta_categories` WHERE `meta_categories`.`id` = 95 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `meta_categories` SET `name` = '#BETABETA', `updated_at` = '2014-11-25 16:10:56' WHERE `meta_categories`.`id` = 95
   (1.4ms)  COMMIT
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template meta_categories/update, application/update with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/cboebel/Documents/Development/Ruby/VerbQ/app/views"
  * "/Users/cboebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/views"
):
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:115:in `find'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in `find_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:35:in `determine_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:127:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:120:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:33:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:26:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:97:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
  /Users/cboebel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:433:in `_run__4261403948446499921__process_action__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:655:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:26:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:48:in `traced_call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:55:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activerecord (4.0.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__1672416812750893188__call__callbacks'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
  railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.9.6.257) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:57:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
  /Users/cboebel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/cboebel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/cboebel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/cboebel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/missing_template.erb within rescues/layout (0.7ms)
```

So.. not sure how to proceed. I've seen various answers on this site about rails needing to told how to respond, and that's borne out as I lose the error when I add the respond_to. What bothers me, though, is that it doesn't seem to execute my code in update.js.erb.

Thanks!

Comment: try this `render 'meta_categories/update'` instead `render 'update.js.erb'`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is here:

```
def update
    # TODO: need uniqueness test for updated Metas
    if current_user.try(:admin?)
      @meta_category.update(meta_category_params)
      flash[:notice]='Meta category has been updated.'
      respond_to do |format|
          format.json { render json: @meta_category, :status => 400 }
          format.js 
      end
    else
      MetaCategoryProposedChange.create(meta_category_id: @meta_category.id,
                                        new_meta_category: meta_category_params[:name],
                                        proposing_user_id: current_user.id)
      flash[:notice]='Your proposed change has been recorded. You will be notified when it has been reviewed.'
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render json: @meta_category, :status => 400 }
        format.js 
      end
    end
```

Comment: Possibly, but if I test with the a user for whom :admin? is true, it still does not work and the MetaCategoryProposedChange branch isn't touched. Also, @meta_category does have a value in the MetaCategoryProposedChange branch. It's loaded as part of a before_action.

Comment: oh I am really sorry, I didn't notice the if block. I just updated. It should work even the user is admin now.

Comment: Sadly, that did not do it. I'm so curious to know why create and delete work, but update does not.